# Deleted json property becomes null

Tags: javascript, json

I got a json that stores columns for a table. I want to delete the Column with the name of 'Foo'. This code removes the Column from my json, but instead of completly deleting it, it leaves a null value in my Columns array.

How do I completley delete it?

```
var json = { 'Columns': [] };

json.Columns.push({ 'Name': 'Foo' });
json.Columns.push({ 'Name': 'Bar' });

$.each(json.Columns, function (index, col) {
    if (col.Name == 'Foo') {
         delete json.Columns[index];
    }
});
```

Result: `{"Columns":[null,{"Name":"Bar"}]}`

Comment: But yes when your JSON contains multiple key-value pair and if you remove more than one key then you have to run a for-loop to remove/skip NULL values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just filter the data or you could splice the arrray, but that's an overkill here I suppose, so go with 
`Array.filter`

```
json.Columns = json.Columns.filter(function(col){
   return col.Name !== 'Foo';
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping for a solution that don't require a for each loop

Answer (score 3):

```
    if (col.Name == 'Foo') {
       json.Columns.splice(index,1);
    }
```

will properly delete the object